# What is name this expression?

Tags: java, android

I have short question. What is name this expression in parameter?Thanks.

```
tv.setOnClickListener(this::getAa);
```

Comment: Didn't know its possible to do this in Java... are you sure ?

Comment: It is method reference introduced in Java 8 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: yes it `Method Reference`

Comment: @MalteseFalcon Yes. Here it is shown an example: https://youtu.be/YKdhLGQnhDY?list=PLrrO3Ef0L8A_8vcwWrQfl21nlxQ2TqlhP&t=5127